# wso2 api manager dashborad Unmapped exception feign.RetryableException: cannot retry due to redirection, in streaming mode executing

Tags: wso2-api-manager

In wso2 api manager 3.2.0 when I run dashboard I get following exception :

```
WARN {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener} - Unmapped exception feign.RetryableException: cannot retry due to redirection, in streaming mode executing POST https://ip address:9443/client-registration/v0.16/register
```

Dashboard config file:

```
## Authentication configuration
auth.configs:
  type: apim
  ssoEnabled: true
  properties:
    adminScope: apim_analytics:admin_carbon.super
    allScopes: apim_analytics:admin apim_analytics:product_manager apim_analytics:api_developer apim_analytics:app_developer apim_analytics:devops_engineer apim_analytics:analytics_viewer apim_analytics:everyone openid apim:api_view apim:subscribe
    adminUsername: admin
    adminPassword: admin
    kmDcrUrl: https://172.25.129.66:9443/client-registration/v0.16/register
    kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://172.25.129.66:9443/oauth2
    kmTokenUrl: https://172.25.129.66:9443/oauth2
    kmUsername: admin
    kmPassword: admin
    portalAppContext: analytics-dashboard
    businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
    cacheTimeout: 30
    baseUrl: https://172.25.129.69:9643
    grantType: authorization_code
    publisherUrl: https://172.25.129.66:9443
    devPortalUrl: https://172.25.129.66:9443
    externalLogoutUrl: https://172.25.129.66:9443/oidc/logout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **kmDcrUrl** should be

```
https://172.25.129.66:9443/client-registration/v0.17/register
```

In API-M 3.2.0, the DCR endpoint version is **v0.17**. In the config you have provided, the version is **v0.16**.

The Dashboard configuration for API-M 3.2.0 can be seen in [Step 4.2 - Point 4](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#step-42-configure-the-analytics-dashboard)